# JavaScript CSS Swapping Function Call

Tags: javascript, css

I have two links in the body of my html page that should make another css file load to make the site dark or light (the site defaults as the dark css style.) The code isn't working though, any input?

Here is a bit of the head with the JS:

```
<link href="dark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/JavaScript" language="javascript">
function light() {
document.write('<link href="light.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
}

function dark() {
document.write('<link href="dark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
}
</script>
```

Here are the links in the body:

```
  <a href="" onClick="light();">Light</a>&nbsp;<a href="" onClick="dark();">Dark</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I can tell you using `document.write()` or `document.writeLn()` are the wrong approaches.

Comment: I seriously doubt that the browser is guaranteed to reload the new css file, even if you have your code all fixed. A more conventional way is to have all the css loaded initially, and modify the class attribute of the elements at run time.

Comment: @user1062058 - This is a simple example of what PeterPeiGuo was describing: http://jsfiddle.net/RSg8F/1/ Note how the `body` class is used to style the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just writing out a new css file each time; you want to change the existing one.

I think this is what you want:

```
<link id="cssFile" id="cssFile" href="dark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/JavaScript" language="javascript">
  function light() {
    document.getElementById("cssFile").href = "light.css");
  }

  function dark() {
    document.getElementById("cssFile").href = "dark.css");
  }
```

**EDIT**

Here's a cleaner version that works with **one** function

```
<input type="button" value="light" onclick="css('light.css')" />
<input type="button" value="dark" onclick="css('dark.css')" />

function css(file) {
   document.getElementById("cssFile").href = file;
}
```

Just note that attaching dom level 0 event handlers is usually frowned upon for non-trivial applications.

I tested this in Chrome, IE, and FF, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but still no luck on that.

Comment: @user1062058 - I just tested this - it works, at least on Chrome.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I messed something up, I'm on Firefox. Do I need to load a default stylesheet? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you'll have a default stylesheet, and you'll dynamically change the href property on it

Comment: Ah, that is simpler than my answer. Although, one function would suffice.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - yes, one function will definitely suffice

Comment: Still no luck on the one function edit... am I missing something obvious?

Comment: nevermind, forgot this line: <link id="cssFile" id="cssFile" href="dark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return setStylesheet('light')">Light</a>

function setStylesheet(type) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'light':
            var other = document.getElementById('darkStylesheet');
        break;
        case 'dark':
            var other = document.getElementById('lightStylesheet');
        break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    if (other) {
        other.parentNode.removeChild(other);
    }

    if (document.getElementById(type + "Stylesheet")) {
        return true;
    }

    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.id = type + "Stylesheet";
    link.href = type + ".css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.type = "text/css";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    return false;
}
```